# Does the name and id need to be the same in a HTML form input

Tags: html

What is the name and id of a input used for, how are they similar and how are they different

Comment: No, they don't have to be the same. Unlike id, name can be used by multiple tags but tags can only have one name whether it's shared or not.

Comment: The [<input> standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) is perfectly clear on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in this example:

```
<label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
<input id="username">
```

`id` can be used to connect inputs with their labels. Also you can use `id` to find the element in JS (DOM manipulation) and add css styles to that input. Although you can do both with `name`, it's not common practice.
In languages like PHP or/and in forms sending data to some url (without reading the form data without getting the values of input items in JS and then sending it through ajax/fetch) `name` is used to label the data being sent to destination.

for example in PHP we read input values like this:

```
$var = $_GET['some_input_name'];
$var_posted = $_POST['some_other_input_name_but_with_post']
```

in this does not work with `id`.

if you send a form data to some url with GET method, you can see your input `name`s added to the action (destination) url.
for example:

```
<form action="http://example.com/" method="get">
    <input name="username" type="text">
</form>
```

will send and attach data to:
`http://example.com/?username=text_entered_in_the_input`